# NameError: uninitialized constant Song ...Programming Ruby

Tags: ruby, class, nameerror

trying to pick up ruby through this programming ruby site and i'm stuck on this syntax

```
class SongList


  def initialize
    @songs = Array.new
  end

  def append(aSong)
    @songs.push(aSong)
    self
  end


  def deleteFirst
    @songs.shift
  end
  def deleteLast
    @songs.pop
  end


end
```

When i go to add a song...

```
list = SongList.new
list.append(Song.new('title1', 'artist1', 1))
```

I get this error message:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Song ...Programming Ruby
```

I saw that i need to require the variable Song, but I'm not sure where to do it within the SongList class....

Comment: You need to create a `Song` class.

Comment: Looks like they're probably using some variant of [this tutorial](http://phrogz.net/programmingruby/frameset.html) which has the class definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Ruby [`Struct`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Struct.html) class :

> A `Struct` is a convenient way to bundle a number of attributes together, using accessor methods, without having to write an explicit class.

```
class SongList
  def initialize
    @songs = [] # use [] instead of Array.new
  end

  def append(aSong)
    @songs.push(aSong)
    self
  end

  def delete_first
    @songs.shift
  end
  def delete_last
    @songs.pop
  end
end

Song = Struct.new(:song_name, :singer, :var)

list = SongList.new
list.append(Song.new('title1', 'artist1', 1))
# => #<SongList:0x9763870
#     @songs=[#<struct Song song_name="title1", singer="artist1", var=1>]> var=1>]>
```